# Double tap to drag no longer works

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad

I used to have the double-tap-to-drag working, where I would tap the trackpad, let go, then tap-and-hold and it would begin dragging.

I temporarily disabled the `Tap to click` setting in System Preferences, and now after I reenabled it, I no longer have double-tap-to-drag. `Tap to click` does work, it's just the dragging that no longer works. I don't see any setting to enable double-tap-to-drag. Is it automatically supposed to work when `Tap to click` is enabled?

I've tried it with `Three finger drag` both enabled and disabled, but nothing works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options…** and check “Enable dragging”.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works even with the setting `without Drag Lock` enabled, as long as the checkbox near `Dragging` is checked.

Comment: This works great. One thing though is when you let go after dragging, it takes a second before it "drops". Any way to get that to be instantly after you let go?

Comment: @Joe None that I know of.